# Why am I getting an "identifier undefined" error?

Tags: c++, file

Essentially I'm trying to read certain lines from a .txt file and I made this function:

```
//Function to read specific lines of .txt files


 std::fstream& GotoLine(std::fstream& file, unsigned int num)
    {
        file.seekg(std::ios::beg);
        for (int i = 0; i < num - 1; ++i) {
            file.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        }
    
        return file;
    }
```

I made the function inside main.cpp and outside the main function at the bottom, so I made sure to prototype it before the main function as such:

```
 std::fstream& GotoLine(std::fstream& file, unsigned int num);
```

but when I try to use it inside the main function it gives an error saying: E0020: identifier "GoToLine" is undefined

This is how I use it inside the main function:

```
GoToLine(inFile, 8);
```

Comment: Works for me: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c1df0e2d18317be4

Comment: It's so weird because I saw this code from another post and it was working fine for that person, I'm using visual studio 2019 idk if that helps

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] that reproduces the error? Like, a complete main.cpp which we can copy-paste and test.

Comment: Turns out it was a visual studio related error. I tried creating another project and it worked. Will be deleting the question. Thank you!

Comment: Completely unrelated: Check that `num != 0` before entering the for loop.

Comment: Very important to prevent unnecessary errors, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

### C++ is case sensitive

The error is simply because while calling the function you are calling `GoToLine(inFile, 8);` with a capital " **T** " whereas in function definition it is small " **t** "

`std::fstream& GotoLine(std::fstream& file, unsigned int num);`

Comment: Thank you very much I noticed that also!

Comment: things like these are very easy to miss and can be very hard to spot